# Configure a nifi processor to run one time

Tags: apache-nifi, processor

Good morning everyone. I hope you'r all keeping safe and staying in home. So my problem is:
I have a nifi project [image: nifi project]

InvokeHttp is doing the "POST" methode and the generateflow processor contain the body of the post methode
all I need to know is how to make this project runs one time : i.e: REST API needs to create one user I need it to be stopped once a user is created ! It's like running this project one and only one time !
Is it possible ?? how can we do it ?

Comment: specify in schedule to repeat task each 1000 years - and it's done.

Comment: @daggett how can I make it ?? what to configure exactly ??

Comment: the scheduling tab of the GenerateFlowFile processor, the default is "0 seconds" which means as fast as possible which is why you have 10k flow files produced

Comment: @BryanBende so how to add it that it will generate one only flow file then stop

Comment: There is no way to do that, something needs to start and stop the processor

Answer (score 0):

You could use a getFile processor that monitors a folder path. When you drop a file into it the processor will pick it up to begin the flow. The default of the processor will remove the file from the system. The flow will not run again unless of course you drop another file into the folder.

But the question is if it is only to run 1 time then why the hassle? Just manually run it once by right clicking on the processor and select run once and be done.

Comment: At that time (2017,2018), the run once option was not available

Answer (score -1):

1111111110sec - Run Schedule
This will make sure to run the processor only once.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ8qc.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Cool!!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf8Qv.png)